# Slow Performance on Microsoft.Web.Services3 Call

Tags: .net, soap, soapui

I am banging my head here. I have a .net 4 console app with a reference to the Microsoft.Web.Services3 dll to make the soap calls a little more user friendly and I am trying to figure out why to make a call to an endpoint using SoapUI it would sale 250ms and when my app executes the call it takes close to a minute.

The return payload is a decent size - about 100KB of xml and it is returning to an array of strings - so it could be that the delay is not in the call but in the array being built?

This is hidden from me as a developer though... if i call

```
dim myStrings() as string
mystrings = clientObj.GetNames()
```

and myStrings has perhaps 3000 names in it when I am done - I am not sure what I can do to help this. I know that if I execute the raw call to the endpoint it takes about 250ms to get the xml returned.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you expecting from the the question, please clarify as it does not stands out clear.

Comment: The more  I tinker with this the more this seems to be tied perhaps to connection pooling or something at the transport level. I am trying to figure out why a request issued from soap ui would be so much faster than the production instance of this app.